# Automatically format numbers inside a String with a single statement?

Tags: java

Let's say i have a text with some characters and numbers, just like this:

`Lorem ipsum 10.2357 dolor sit amet, 10.0000 consectetur adipiscing 50.9651 elit.`

How can i get a final String like this:

`Lorem ipsum 10.23 dolor sit amet, 10.00 consectetur adipiscing 50.96 elit.`

with a single statement, without creating additional methods?

**-> Update**
I want to do this in a single statement because i want to do it inside jasper reports, which does not support multi-statements. I could create a method for this but that would be too much work for just a simple thing

Comment: Do you have any formatting rules? Or simply truncating part after `.dd` will be OK like `1.5678` to `1.56`?

Comment: Can you explain where the restrictions "with a single statement, without creating additional methods" come from? It sounds like some kind of assignment.

Comment: @ci_ See my update on the question

Comment: Just make a method, there isn't anything too simple for a method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it with a regex ([regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression))

E.g:

```
 str.replaceAll("(\\d+)\\.?(\\d{0,2})\\d+", "$1.$2")
```

This will not work in all cases.

Comment: That's right! As my numbers on the string will always have more than two digits it will always work. Thanks.

Comment: @MateusViccari What should be result of replacing `1.999`? Should it be rounded up to `2.00` or `1.99` is OK?

Comment: @Pshemo If it was 2.00 it would be better but precision is not so important in my case.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be achieved in one line.

```
    String s = "Lorem ipsum 10.2357 dolor sit amet, 10.0000 consectetur adipiscing 50.9651 elit";
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
    String[] sub = s.split(" ");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i=0; i<sub.length; i++) {
        try {
            double d = Double.parseDouble(sub[i]);
            sb.append(df.format(d));
            sb.append(" ");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            sb.append(sub[i]);
            sb.append(" ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Answer (score -1):

I am no Java expert but likely you are looking for `printf` eqivalent, which in Java is:

`System.out.format("PI is %.2f", 3.14)`

Look up the format options for `%f`

Comment: That won't do what is asked for in the question, which has a string with numbers as input.